# compare date retrieved from datefield to current date in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to compare a date that i retrieve from o datefield (xtype: 'datefield',) to the current date.
What i've done is the next :

```
validateDatedebut : function(dateDebutID) {
            var dateDebutField = Ext.getCmp(dateDebutID);
            var dateDepuis = Ext.Date.format(dateDebutField.getValue(),'d/m/Y'); 
            var dateCourrante = Ext.Date.format(new Date(),'d/m/Y'); 
            if (dateCourrante < dateDepuis) {
                alert("date value provided is larger" );
            } else {
                    alert("date value provided is less" );
            }
}
```

Where dateDebutID is the ID of my datefield.
The problem is that I always get "date value provided is less".

Comment: While debugging the  dateDepuis is larger than dateCourrante ? I mean logical the comparison should show the opposite from what you get?

Comment: Ext.Date.format, formats the date in a given format and return string. So you are comparing string instead of date object.

Comment: kostas ch yes of course when while debuging i've found that dateDepuis is larger than dateCourrante . 
And of course the comparison should show the opposite of what i get.

Comment: sushant jain this is what i suspected also, any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Dont format the date and compare it. If your date includes time and you want to exclude time then after formatting you need to convert the string into date object again using Ext.Date.parse

Comment: Do you have an example howa to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
validateDatedebut : function(dateDebutID) {
            var dateDebutField = Ext.getCmp(dateDebutID);
            var dateDepuis_formated = Ext.Date.format(dateDebutField.getValue(),'d/m/Y'); 
            var dateCourrante_formated = Ext.Date.format(new Date(),'d/m/Y'); 

           var dateDepuis = Ext.Date.parse(dateDepuis_formated ,'d/m/Y'); 
           var dateCourrante = Ext.Date.parse(dateCourrante_formated ,'d/m/Y'); 
            if (dateCourrante < dateDepuis) {
                alert("date value provided is larger" );
            } else {
                    alert("date value provided is less" );
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

```
                    var dateDepuis = new Date(dateDebutField.getValue()); 
                    var dateCourrante = new Date(); 
                    isLarger = this.compareDate(dateCourrante,dateDepuis);
                    if (isLarger) {
                        alert("date value provided is larger" );
                    } else {
                        alert("date value provided is less" );
                    }
```

Thanks for you reaction !